# C macro to produce token from numeric variable value

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How can I define a C macro that will generate a variable name (token) based on the value of a variable passed to that function?  In the example below, looking for a valid version of the MEMBER macro.

e.g. Given a structure something line the following, I need to define a macro that will produce a variable name based on the value of a variable passed to the function.

```
struct foo {
    uint32_t bar0_data;
    uint32_t bar0_status;

    uint32_t bar1_data;
    uint32_t bar1_status;

    ...
};

#define MEMBER(x, n, f) x -> bar ## n ## _ ## f

void write_val(struct foo *foo, int which_bar)
{
    MEMBER(foo, which_bar, data) = 1;
    MEMBER(foo, which_bar, status) = 2;
}
```

This applies to a giant structure that has different variations on this theme, so defining a new structure with an array of member structures is not an option.

Comment: You understand that macros run as part of the preprocessor?  i.e. *before* the compiler, and certainly not at runtime (which is when variables acquire values).

Comment: I'll add that as a static type language the type of a variable must be known at compilation time, but I guess that leads to a less discussed consequence - you need to now the name of the variable at compile time.

Comment: You could, depending on your variables and values, make an array (or perhaps a different suitable structure). e.g. `struct bar { uint32_t data, status; }; struct foo { struct bar bars[2]; };`. Then your function is just `foo->bars[which_bar]->data = 1; foo->bars[which_bar]->status = 2;`.

Comment: Yes, understood that this is done by the preprocessor before runtime variable value is known.  Just curious if anyone has a clever idea to workaround this.  I suppose you could compute an offset from the base value using the variable value, but that seems clumsy.

Comment: In C, the notion of dynamic variables are usually accomplished with a hash table or lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not allow you to create a dynamic name in that way.

You can simulate it by using a lookup table.

However, you actually just want to find a particular field in `foo` from runtime data. This can be done in several ways. A switch statement, for example.

```
switch (which_bar) {
case 0: foo->bar0_data = 1;
        foo->bar0_status = 1;
        break;
...
}
```

If you would rather use a literal table, you can store offsets for the fields.

```
offset_t bar_data[] = {
    offsetof(struct foo, bar0_data),
    offsetof(struct foo, bar1_data),
    ...
};

offset_t bar_status[] = {
    offsetof(struct foo, bar0_status),
    ...
};

#define BAR_DATA(FOO, WHICH) \
    (*(uint32_t *)((char *)(FOO) + bar_data[WHICH]))
#define BAR_STATUS(FOO, WHICH) \
    (*(uint32_t *)((char *)(FOO) + bar_status[WHICH]))

BAR_DATA(foo, which_bar) = 1;
BAR_STATUS(foo, which_bar) = 1;
```

But, it seems you would be better served by defining a structure to represent "`bar`", and define an array of them within `foo`.

```
struct bar {
    uint32_t data;
    uint32_t status;
};

struct foo {
    struct bar bar[MAX_BARS];
};

foo->bar[which_bar].data = 1;
foo->bar[which_bar].status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be thinking of languages that allow you to "execute" a text that you generate on the fly (like `JavaScript`). `C` is different in that the conversion from source text to the running binary happens in these steps:

1. Run the `pre-processor` - that is where the text of the program is **modified** with macro expansions and other rules (like `#include` directives)
2. Run the `compiler` - this converts the result of step 1 into machine code (whether through an intermediate step of using an `Assembler` language or directly)
3. Link the resulting object file(s) with libraries (if necessary), resolve all the external symbols and produce the "final" binary that you run (or a static/dynamic library - depending on your output)

In any case the **run-time** behavior happens *way* past the `pre-processor` step, so what you are looking for is not possible in `C` language (short of writing a self-modifying program that re-compiles and re-launches itself)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, figured out that one way to implement this macro assuming that each instance appears at a fixed offset is:

```
#define DELTA(m1, m2) (offsetof(foo_t, m2) - offsetof(foo_t, m1))
#define MEMBER(x, n, f)                                 \
    *(uint32_t *)(((uint8_t *)& x -> bar0_ ## f) +      \
                  (DELTA(bar0_ ## f, bar1_ ## f) * n))
```

It does not generate variable name tokens, as initially requested, but can be used to access the values w/o having to produce the names.

Comment: You can't generally assume fixed offsets.